# Get a comma separated list of first cell values for rows with classname (using Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, string, delimited

Trying to grab ids from the table below when a row is selected. For example, the jquery should return: "12,14"..My code below returns empty string?

My html:

```
<table id="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>first</th>
           <th>last</th>
           <th>number</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
...etc...
   <tr class="selected">
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>9999</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Lee</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>8888</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="selected">
      <td>14</td>
      <td>JJ</td>
      <td>Wolf</td>
      <td>77777</td>
   </tr>
... etc..
</table>
```

My Jquery:

```
 var nameIDs = $('table tr.selected td:first').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
```

Comment: First, fix you HTML. Also, use `:nth-child`: http://jsfiddle.net/karthikr12/cvsLt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `value` is not defined for td, you need to use `this.innerText` or `this.innerHTML`, Also use `first-child` instead of `first`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/873X6/1/)**

```
var nameIDs = $('table tr.selected td:first-child').map(function () {
    return this.innerText;
}).get().join(',');
```

**Edit**

The html is also invalid, you missed the closing `</td>` in second `td` for all rows.

*Change*

```
<td>Smith<td>
```

To

```
<td>Smith</td>
```

Comment: For some reason, it only grabs the first selected row only?

Comment: Your html is also invalid, close second td in all rows

Comment: This is just quick mockup..the real html has the closing tds.

Comment: First will return only first, you need first child for first child of all the tr

Comment: Thats correct, need all first tds of all selected rows

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
var elems = $(".selected>td:first-child");
for(var key in elems )
  elems[key] = $(elems[key]).html();
var values = elems.join(",");
```

The result is in the string `values`